# Elasticsearch: Adding new field to nested object with value based on existing field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an existing index. Document, say E, has a nested object, say C. I need to add few new fields to C. Some of these new fields would have a default value, while one would be set based on value of a field in E.

What is optimum way of doing this?

Comment: COPY TO, or create a new mapping  and copy_to

Comment: Do you need to do this to the new docs or to existing docs?

Comment: both existing and new ones

Comment: Ok, for the existing fields you can use update_by_query with the script. For the new docs, you can use the ingest pipeline for the fields generation, or if you use some ETL (like Logstash, NiFi e.t.c.) you can add this function in the ETL level